# "I have found it working". Is this sentence correct grammatically?

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I have confusion with a sentence and I would like to know if this sentence is correct or not:

> I have found it working.

Comment: Where did you see that? On the internet, people whip out sentences and often write shorter things that are not completely accurate but accurate enough for comments on fb, for example.

Comment: It's syntactically valid, but we can't say whether it's "correct" or not until you provide more context, and tell us what you ***want*** it to mean. (There aren't many contexts where your exact utterance might be used, so it's probably ***not*** what you want.)

Comment: [I am confused about x,]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one example of acceptable but not elegant usage. "Is the motor damaged?" "No it is not. I have examined it. I have found it working."

Answer (score 1):

Additional context would be helpful to verify if the sentence is conveying the intended message or not, and if there is a better way to phrase this that is clearer or more polished.

I assume the author has determined that something supposedly broken is actually working.  Depending on the situation, there are many ways to state this.

Examples:

> "I have finished examining the bug you asked me to look at.  I followed the steps to reproduce.  However, **it appears to be working as designed**."

> "I thought you said the lightbulb was out?  I just checked and **it is working fine for me**."

> "Can you remind me to check Grandma's computer again tomorrow?  I was on it earlier today and **found it to be working**.  I'm not sure why she is having trouble with it."